# Creación de trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy haciendo un trigger que al insertar un valor que comience con el numero 0 no lo inserte pero si el numero es mayor que  0  si lo deje insertar

como pueden ver en esta imagen en la columna **cantidad** muchos artículos los han insertado con valores que comienzan en 0 pero esto ya no puede ocurrir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código de lo que llevo**

```
CREATE TRIGGER Tr_Articulos_Restringidos 
ON  [dbo].[tblmvtoinventarios]  FOR INSERT 
AS
DECLARE @cantidad numeric 
SELECT @cantidad = MAX(cantidad)  FROM  tblmvtoinventarios T0
INNER JOIN tblarticulos T1 ON T1.codigo = T0.codigo 
WHERE T1.codunidad = 'Und.'
IF (@cantidad  (OPERACION)) BEGIN

        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RAISERROR ('No se puede hacer la insercion de esta factura si la cantidad tiene el valor 0 comunicate con el area de sistemas',
                                                 -- Message text.  
                   16,                           -- Severity.  
                   1                             -- State.  
                   ) 
    END
    GO
```

el inner join es porque los que están definidos como Und. no pueden insertar con el valor  0 pero los que estén definidos con otro tipo si pueden insertar con valor en  0

Comment: qué tipo de dato es la columna `cantidad`?

Comment: @Lamak Es numeric(20, 6)

Comment: Primero que todo, tienes que pensar en un trigger como algo que se ejecuta una vez por proceso de inserción de datos, no necesariamente una vez por cada fila de datos que estás insertando. Dado esto, por ejemplo si estás insertando 100 filas en la tabla, y 1 fila tiene un valor 0, qué quieres que pase?

Comment: Si de esa  100 filas insertan 1  que tiene valor  0 y tiene el código Und.  no lo deje insertar  pero si lo insertan con valor en 0  y el código es  diferente a Und. lo deje insertar

Comment: Pero ahi no estas validando el numero que te llego, si no uno que estas recuperando por eso te esta dejando pasar deberias de validarlo con el new.cantidad

Comment: Por eso necesito la ayuda

Comment: Pero qué pasa con las otras 99 filas?, se insertan?, o falla todo el proceso de inserción?

Comment: Se insertan solo no deja insertar las que estén con el valor 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al trabajar con triggers, tienes que tener en cuenta que los datos a manejar se encuentran en las tablas virtuales inserted y deleted (se usan de acuerdo al tipo de operación que estés realizando).

También tienes que entender que el trigger se ejecuta una vez por operación y no una vez por fila, por lo que tienes que hacer que el trigger pueda manejar varias filas al mismo tiempo.

Aquí dejo un ejemplo basado en tu código para ejemplificar como quedaría.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Tr_Articulos_Restringidos 
ON  [dbo].[tblmvtoinventarios]  FOR INSERT 
AS

IF EXISTS(
            SELECT *
            FROM  inserted i
            INNER JOIN tblarticulos a ON i.codigo = a.codigo 
            WHERE a.codunidad = 'Und.'
            AND i.cantidad < 1
        )
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    RAISERROR ('No se puede hacer la insercion de esta factura si la cantidad tiene el valor 0 comunicate con el area de sistemas',
                                                -- Message text.  
                16,                           -- Severity.  
                1                             -- State.  
                ) ;
END
GO
```

También puedes crear una CHECK CONSTRAINT que valide por fila sin necesidad de usar triggers para poder mantener un control más preciso. Para hacer eso, necesitas una función que traiga la unidad del artículo.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UnidadArticulo(
    @codigo int --Cambiar tipo de dato
)
RETURNS varchar(5) --Cambiar tipo de dato
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN ( SELECT codunidad
            FROM tblarticulos
            WHERE codigo = @codigo);
END
GO

ALTER TABLE tblmvtoinverios
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_Articulos_Restringidos CHECK (cantidad >= 1 OR dbo.UnidadArticulo(codigo) <> 'Und.');

GO
```

Por cierto, debes recordar que en SQL las operaciones deben ser completas, por lo que no puedes pedir que solo se inserten unas y las otras no.

Comment: Si bien esto está correcto según el código que posteó el op, en un comentario dice que si algún valor dentro del proceso de inserción es menor a 1, debe no insertar sólo ese valor y sí el resto. Por lo que no debería fallar todo el `insert`

Comment: @Lamak pero eso sólo se puede conseguir insertando cada fila en una transacción distinta. Recuerda las [propiedades ACID de SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

Comment: No necesariamente, simplemente podría ser un `instead of` trigger, y que haga la validación filtrando los valores menor a 1

Comment: No me parece que sea una buena idea. Necesitarías una tabla alternativa para capturar los artículos que no se insertaron y poder tener un control de los errores. De otra forma, estás ocultando un error y eso causa confusiones al largo plazo.

Comment: Sí, pero es finalmente el requerimiento del op